# Расчет каждого поля при UPDATE таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

У меня есть вот такая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно создать триггер который, после UPDATE saldo_in_som и saldo _out_som будет записывать
defference = saldo _out_som - saldo_in_som
Я создал вот такой вот триггер:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_after () RETURNS trigger AS $First$
BEGIN

UPDATE consolid SET defference = saldo_in_som - saldo_out_som;
UPDATE consolid SET difference_usd = saldo_in_usd - saldo_out_usd;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$First$
LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER differ
AFTER UPDATE ON consolid FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_after ();
```

Но он выдает ошибку: Подзапрос вернул больше одного выражения, как мне сделать так что бы он рассчитывал difference для каждой строки?

Comment: А почему бы просто не сделать столбцы вычислимыми?

Comment: Спасибо помогло)